# How to prove that in a matrix, the column is still ordered after "sorting every data by column THEN by row"

Tags: algorithm, sorting, matrix

conduct the following steps in a matrix:
1. sorting every data in each column;
2. sorting every data in each row;

PROVE that the data in each column is STILL ordered.
I don't know how to prove that.

Comment: Please provide an example. Is all data contained in the matrix of the same type?

Comment: Yes, it's a matter of sorting algorithms instead of linear algebra. All the elements in the matrix can (say) be integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we will be looking at a matrix, which has been column-sorted. We will show, that after row-sorting is done each element will be not lesser than the one below it.

Let `x` be value of an item in the top row.

Let `n` be number of elements in the top row which are greater or equal to `x`.

`x` must be in the left `n` spots of matrix.

That means, that there are at least `n` elements in the row below which are not lesser than `x` - that is because each of the `n` elements in top row, which are not lesser than `x` have something not lesser below them.

This means, that below `x` there is an element that is greater than `x`.

With induction we can apply that to every row.